# Anova not working at multilevel analysis - "$ operator not defined for this S4 class"

Tags: r, lme4

I got a problem running my code in R when trying to do an anova related to my multilevel analysis. I always get the error:

> $ operator not defined for this S4 class

```
## Model 0: Model without teams - grand-mean-centered
h2_0_gmc <- lm(PSS_mean ~ PCT_mean_gmc, data = dat_h1_2)

## Model 1: Model with teams - fixed intercept, random slope - grand-mean-centered
h2_1_gmc <- lmer(PSS_mean ~ PCT_mean_gmc + (1 | teamcode), data = dat_h1_2)

## Model 2: Model with teams - random intercept, random slope - grand-mean-centered
h2_2_gmc <- lmer(PSS_mean ~ PCT_mean_gmc + (PCT_mean_gmc | teamcode), data = dat_h1_2)

## Comparison of models
anova(h2_0_gmc, h2_1_gmc, h2_2_gmc)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare a model with no random effects to a model with a random effect using lme4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019807/how-to-compare-a-model-with-no-random-effects-to-a-model-with-a-random-effect-us)

Comment: @AkselA This answer is quite old. I wouldn't consider it up-to-date concerning the current lme4 version (although it's points are still valid).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply reverse the order of arguments:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm0 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, sleepstudy)

anova(fm0, fm1)
#Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class

anova(fm1, fm0)
#refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
#Data: sleepstudy
#Models:
#fm0: Reaction ~ Days
#fm1: Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)
#    Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
#fm0  3 1906.3 1915.9 -950.15   1900.3                             
#fm1  6 1763.9 1783.1 -875.97   1751.9 148.35      3  < 2.2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**Technical explanation:**

`anova` is an S3 generic. S3 method dispatch works according to the class of the object passed as the first argument. If you put the `lm` fit first, `anova.lm` is called and it can't deal with "merMod" objects. If you put the `lmer` fit first, `anova.merMod` is called and this method can also deal with "lm"  objects.